# Strange PHP Warning (Unable to load dynamic library: no-debug-non-zts-20100525)

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

I temporarily set apc.enable_cli=1 in apc.ini, then run php -r "apc_clear_cache();" in the terminal to clear APC cache but this is what I got:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so' - /opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mysql.so' - /opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mysqli.so' - /opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so' - /opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so' - /opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm running PHP-FPM 5.4.3, Nginx 1.3.1 and APC 3.1.10 on an Ubuntu Server 12.04 (VPS).
Do you have any idea of what these errors mean?

Comment: Most likely your php-cli is using a different php.ini file, one with different extensions/paths to extensions set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors mean that the file `/opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so` does not exist, while your PHP configuration wants to load it.  Either make the file exist (again?), or modify your PHP configuration to not load the file.  Also, `/opt/php5` is not an Ubuntu-standard location for PHP installation, so you've done *something* custom to the machine -- I'd start by reviewing your notes on what you did there.

Comment: @c2h5oh: Seems there's no php.ini for php-cli:

php --ini

(same errors posted in 1st post)

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini

Comment: yeah I compiled nginx and php5-fpm in /opt. I searched for that extension in php.ini file but I can't find it!

Comment: Uhm, I tried what suggested here:
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?s=40996bbf8311616ad51ae8a6a16568a1&p=6775082&postcount=2

So I found out that those files (mysql.so, mycrypt.so, etc) was in /usr/lib/php5/20090626/, I copied them to /opt/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ but now I get this:


PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

and so on for every of this files...